# What is the best way to add small numbers to the corner of each cell in a table or grid?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I'm trying to make a simple game involving a 10x10 grid, where each cell in the grid will need to contain a large letter in the center, and a small number in one of the corners. Like this:

[image]

Currently, the best idea I've had involves making 100 different `JLabel` components that correspond to each cell from jLabel00 to jLabel99, and using `null` layout to manually layer them over the bottom-right corner of each cell of a Table. However, this is going to cause a lot of repetitiveness in my code and UI even if I add the labels to an `ArrayList` (assuming I *can* even do that).

Does anyone know of a more elegant solution?

Comment: Use a drawing JPanel to create the grid, letters, and numbers.  The Oracle tutorial, [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) will show you how.

Comment: Some ideas are examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bswing%5d%20JDigit).

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the one of the cells at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. What I'm most interested in knowing is if the 'small number' could be entirely outside the right and bottom most point of the large letter. If so, it's a simple matter of using a `GridBagLayout` with four cells, only two of which (top left and bottom right) contain a visible element.

Comment: That GBL suggestion might [look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTPLq.png)..

Comment: Here's a [single cell](https://imgur.com/TSoWSy0). The number only needs space to fit a single digit, and I'm not picky about how it looks resized, or even making it resizable. I supposed if I had to I'd keep the letter in the center but move the number with the border? Anyway your GBL example looks like it'd be perfect. I'll learn about it and try it out the next chance I get to work on it. Thanks a ton! @AndrewThompson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The kind of layout seen above can easily be made using a `GridBagLayout` for the 'cells' and a `GridLayout` to arrange those cells in rows. The code could use a factory method to produce the cells. It might take a number and a `char` or single character `String` for the letter. This code 'cheats' by assuming the number is a Unicode code point.

This is the method that makes a cell panel:

```
private JPanel getCellPanel(int i) {
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    p.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    JLabel l1 = new JLabel(new String(Character.toChars(i)));
    l1.setFont(l1.getFont().deriveFont(30f));
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    p.add(l1, gbc);

    JLabel l2 = new JLabel();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    p.add(l2, gbc);

    JLabel l3 = new JLabel();
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    p.add(l3, gbc);

    JLabel l4 = new JLabel(new String("" + i));
    l4.setFont(l4.getFont().deriveFont(12f));
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    p.add(l4, gbc);

    return p;
}
```

The complete source code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class BigLetterLittleNumber {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    BigLetterLittleNumber() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        ui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 13, 2, 2));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
        for (int ii=65; ii<91; ii++) {
            ui.add(getCellPanel(ii));
        }
    }

    private JPanel getCellPanel(int i) {
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        p.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        JLabel l1 = new JLabel(new String(Character.toChars(i)));
        l1.setFont(l1.getFont().deriveFont(30f));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        p.add(l1, gbc);

        JLabel l2 = new JLabel();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        p.add(l2, gbc);

        JLabel l3 = new JLabel();
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        p.add(l3, gbc);

        JLabel l4 = new JLabel(new String("" + i));
        l4.setFont(l4.getFont().deriveFont(12f));
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        p.add(l4, gbc);

        return p;
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                BigLetterLittleNumber o = new BigLetterLittleNumber();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```